# Why does node.js print stack traces for errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does node.js print a stacktrace in the REPL whenever an `Error` object is created (and not thrown)? Other REPLs don't seem to have this behavior by default, and I can't see a use case for it.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Exception('something bad happened')
Exception('something bad happened',)
```

Node:

```
$ node
> new Error('something bad happened')
Error: something bad happened
    at repl:1:1
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:504:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Chrome:

```
new Error('something bad happened')
Error: something bad happened(…)
```

Comment: It is a part of the Error itself. In REPL the error is evaluated and printed. if you do `var a = new Error('...')` it doesn't show anything.

Comment: In node, in windows anyway. I get -> `> new Error('something bad happened')` -> `[Error: something bad happened]`